# How to achieve rounding upto 2 decimals with padding in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, formatting, hiveql

Below is the issue which i want to address, in hive query itself, rather than taking data in POJO and then applying formatting (DefaultFormatter etc.) in my downstream program

```
hive> SELECT ROUND(0.605,2);
0.61
-- Result      = 0.61
-- Expectation = 0.61

hive> SELECT ROUND(0.604, 2);
0.6
--- Result      = 0.6
--- Expectation = 0.60
```

how to modify select construct in such a manner which returns decimals with 2 digits padded regardless of their value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string printf(string format, Obj... args)` function, which is based on [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

```
select printf('%.2f',0.604);
```

Result:

```
0.60
```

You do not need to use round():

```
select printf('%.2f',0.605);
```

Result:

```
0.61
```